# Asp.net MVC using json

Tags: asp.net-mvc, json, asp.net-mvc-4

I want to calculate addition of two numbers in asp.net mvc.My code is below.

```
 public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }

    public JsonResult Calculate(int a,int b)
    {
        return Json(a + b);
    }
```

Index.cshtml code is below:

```
 <table>
    <tr>
        <td><input type="text" id="s1"/></td>
        <td>+</td>
        <td><input type="text" id="s2"/>=</td>
        <td><div id="result"></div></td>
    </tr>
    <tr><td><input type="submit" value="Calculate" id="btnCalc"/></td></tr>
</table>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#btnCalc').click(function () {
            var a = $('#s1').val(),b=$('#s2').val();
            $.post("/Home/Calculate", { a: a,b:b }, function (data) {
                $('#result').text(data.Text);
            }, "json");
        });
    });
</script>
```

But when I click to calculate button nothing happened.Where I am wrong.(Sorry my english is bad :( )

Comment: What do you mean "nothing happens"? Is there an error message in the console?

Comment: don't show anything in result div

Answer (score 1):

In your javascript, you need to do this:

```
var a = $('#s1').val();
var b = $('#s2').val();

// {a: a, b: b} might work, but I can't test it right now
$.post('/home/calculate', 'a=' + a + '&b=' + b, function(data) {
    $('#result').text(data.Text);
});
```

In your controller:

```
[HttpPost] //This isn't required, but it will prevent GET requests if that's what you want to do
public JsonResult(int a, int b)
{
    int result = a + b;
    return Json(new {Text = result});
}
```

The main problem is that in your javascript, you were referencing a Text property of `data`, but you weren't returning that from your controller

Answer (score 0):

I found my mistake. Might be helpful to someone.

```
<table>
<tr>
    <td><input type="text" id="s1"/>+</td>
   <td><input type="text" id="s2"/>=</td>
    <td><div id="result"></div></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td><input type="submit" id="btn"/></td></tr>
```

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#btn").click(function() {
            var a = $('#s1').val();
            var b = $("#s2").val();
            $.post("/Home/Calc", { a: a,b:b}, function (data) {
                $('#result').text(data.Text);
            }, "json");
        });});
```

```
 [HttpPost]
        public JsonResult Calc(int a,int b)
        {
            int result = a + b;
            return Json(new {Text=result});
        }

        public class Result
        {
            public string Text { get; set; }
        }
```